# Facebook $this->facebook->api('me/albums') returning empty array

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I have developed a facebook app get all profile pictures of user. The issue is that app is working for me, but same page returns empty array if i logged in with another facebook account. Following is my code

```
$albums = $this->facebook->api('me/albums'); // api call to facebook to fech all albums of the given page
print_r($albums['data']);
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you did not go though [Login Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review), so the required `user_photos` permission will only work for users with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester).